# Minimum number of operations to turn all $1's$ to $0's$ in an $N\times N$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Imagine an $N\times N$ matrix where some elements are $1$ and others are $0$. Touching an element toggles itself and all those in the same row or column as it. The problem is to determine the minimum number of moves to get the entire matrix to be $0's$. First, I would like to determine if it is possible, and if it is, then determine the minimum number of operations.

This is for a programming challenge, but I know it boils down to a math problem. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some observations that may be useful.

(I’m going to replace $N$ by $n$.) For $1\le r,c\le n$ let $M_{r,c}$ be the $n\times n$ matrix with ones in row $r$, ones in column $c$, and zeroes everywhere else. If the original $n\times n$ matrix is $A_0$, and $A_k$ is the matrix after $k$ moves, then the result of touching the entry in row $r$, column $c$ on the $(k+1)$-st move is $A_{k+1}=A_k+M_{r,c}$, where the addition is modulo $2$. Matrix addition modulo $2$ is associative and commutative, so a given set of $m$ moves results in the same final matrix $A_m$ irrespective of the order in which the moves are made. Moreover, $M_{r,c}+M_{r,c}=\mathbf{0}$, the $n\times n$ zero matrix, so making any move more than once is wasteful: making it an even number of times does nothing, and making it an odd number of times has the same effect as making it once.

Suppose, then, that we make $m$ distinct moves, $M_{r_1,c_1},\ldots,M_{r_m,c_m}$. Say that a row $r$ is *odd* if it is flipped an odd number of times (i.e., $r_k=r$ for an odd number of indices $k$), and similarly that a column is odd if it is flipped an odd number of times. Then this set of moves flips the $\langle r,c\rangle$ entry if and only if either row $r$ is odd and column $c$ is even, or row $r$ is even and column $c$ is odd. That is, if

$$\begin{align*}
R_o&=\{r:\text{row }r\text{ is odd}\}\;,\\
R_e&=\{r:\text{row }r\text{ is even}\}\;,\\
C_o&=\{c:\text{column }c\text{ is odd}\}\;,\text{ and}\\
C_e&=\{c:\text{column }c\text{ is even}\}\;,
\end{align*}$$

the entries that are flipped by this set of moves are the ones whose coordinates are in $(R_o\times C_e)\cup(R_e\times C_o)$. If we permute the rows so that the odd rows are at the top and permute the columns so that the odd columns are at the left, and if $A_0=\mathbf{0}$, the result of applying these $m$ moves is

$$A_m=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{0}_{|R_o|\times|C_o|}&\mathbf{1}_{|R_o|\times|C_e|}\\\mathbf{1}_{|R_e|\times|C_o|}&\mathbf{0}_{|R_e|\times|C_e|}\end{bmatrix}\;,$$

where $\mathbf{1}$ is a matrix with all entries $1$.

It’s actually sufficient to determine what positions can be reached from the zero matrix. Suppose that $\mathscr{R}$ is the set of matrices reachable from $\mathbf{0}$, and we wish to determine whether a position $B$ is reachable from some $A_0$. $B$ is reachable from $A_0$ if and only if $B+A_0$ is reachable from $A_0+A_0=\mathbf{0}$, so we need only determine whether $B+A_0\in\mathscr{R}$. This reduces the problem to determining whether a given matrix can be reduced to the form

$$A_m=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{1}\\\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{0}\end{bmatrix}$$

by some permutation of its rows and some (possibly different) permutation of its columns.